# What to do if no answer was helpful, I was able to solve the problem but don't remember the exact solution?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, self-answer

In an effort to have an accepted answer in each of my questions, I went back to an old question that I had asked and where I only got one answer, which was not really helpful as the answerer's english was hard to understand. Later I was able to find the cause of the error and fix it, but forgot to provide an answer to my question with the solution, and now I don't remember exactly how I solved the problem, but I have a general idea...

**What should I do in this case?**

1. Accept the only answer, even though it wasn't really helpful, and write a comment about what was wrong? (I don't really see the point behind this)
2. Answer my own question with a general idea about what was the reason behind the error and accept it?
3. Leave the question unanswered?

Comment: 4. Try to remember what your solution was, but give up and get yourself a cup of coffee.

Comment: you could write an answer and not accept it. In this way there is still motivation for others to write a better answer while someone looking for an answer will have at least your answer to start with

Comment: 5. Recreate the problem so you can solve it again and write a full answer (The problem is reproducible, isn't it?)

Comment: @jwodder I guess, with enough time and motivation, I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tobi303 That's what I'll do in case I don't manage to write a sufficiently useful answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Please don't accept an unhelpful answer.

If you feel you can leave an answer that may be helpful to other users, please do.

Comment: Yes. A "general idea" answer is more useful that no answer at all. And in case somebody provides a more comprehensive, step by step answer in the future, you can always un-accept your answer and accept theirs.

Comment: Right! Thanks to you both :)

Comment: And you can always update your answer later with more details, should they come back to you (which may happen already when you start writing).